# ¿Cómo crear una cesta adaptable sin desorden usando flex/flexbox CSS?

Tags: html5, css3, flexbox

Tengo un diseño completo sobre una cesta, a pesar de seguir un gran seguimiento en los estilos `CSS`, mediante uso de porcentajes, el diseño no queda completamente a mi agrado, al hacer responsive en ir achicando la pantalla del navegador, este se desordena de una manera no agradable, a continuación les enlazo el desorden:

[image: cesta con un producto]

Como se puede observar existen un desorden, pienso que no debería, existe el espacio suficiente para ordenarse, en cada titulo en su respectiva información.

Este es mi código:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, ::after, ::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    color: #222222;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background-color: #f8f9fb;
}

ul li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    list-style: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

img,
.basket-module,
.basket-labels,
.basket-product {
  width: 100%;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

#basket {
  clear: both;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 1rem 0;
}

.item-heading,
.item-price,
.item-quantity,
.item-subtotal,
.basket,
.basket-module,
.basket-labels,
.basket-item,
.basket-price,
.basket-quantity,
.basket-subtotal,
.basket-product,
.product-image,
.product-image-order,
.product-details-order,
.product-details {
  float: left;
}

.item-heading,
.item-price,
.item-quantity,
.item-subtotal {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item-heading {
    padding-left: 10.375rem;
}
.item-price {
    padding-left: 13.7rem;
}

.item-quantity {
      padding-left: 7.5rem;
}
.item-subtotal {
  padding-left: 7.1rem;
}

.basket {
  width: 70%;
}

.basket,
.basket-cart {
  padding: 0 1rem;
  /*padding-top: 150px;*/
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.basket-cart {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
}

.basket-module {
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.basket-labels {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-top: 1.625rem;
}

.basket-item {
  width: 100%; /*55*/
}


.basket-price {
  width: 19%;
}

.basket-quantity {
  width: 15%;
}

.basket-subtotal {
  width: 5%;
}

.basket-subtotal {
  text-align: right;
}

.basket-remove-item {
  /*bottom: 1.125rem;*/
  float: right;
  /*position: absolute;*/
  right: 0;
  text-align: right;
  /*width: 45%;*/
}

.basket-remove-item button {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #777;
  float: none;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}


.basket-product {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  position: relative;
}

.product-image {
  width: 10%; /*25% 35%*/
}

.product-image-order {
  width: 14%;
}

.product-frame {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

.product-details {
  width: 35%;/*70% 65%*/
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.product-details h2 {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.product-details-order {
  width: 81%;
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.product-details-order h2 {
    font-size: 13px;
}

.summary {
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  padding: 1rem;
  /*position: fixed;*/
  width: 250px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.summary-total-items {
  color: #666;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.summary-subtotal {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.subtotal-title,
.subtotal-value,
.promo-title,
.promo-value,
.discount-title,
.discount-value,
.expand-title,
.expand-coupon,
.total-title,
.total-value {
  color: #111;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.subtotal-value,
.total-value {
  text-align: right;
}

.total-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.promo-title,.discount-title {
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
}

.promo-value,.discount-value {
  color: #8B0000;
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
  width: 30%;
}

.expand-form {
  display:none;
  clear: both;
}

.expand-coupon {
  color: #4D8FE5;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: right;
}

.promo-code-field {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
  width: 48%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
  -o-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
}

.promo-code-field:hover,
.promo-code-field:focus {
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

.responseCoupon {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0.9;
  position: absolute; 
  bottom: 71px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  left: 15px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 250px;
}

.promo-code {
  font-size: 16px;
    /*text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-left: 20px;*/
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
}

.delete-promo-code {
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 13px;
  /*
  color: #8B0000;
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    width: 30%;*/
}

.summary-total {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.summary-subtotal,
.summary-total {
  clear: both;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
}

.summary-promo {
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.summary-checkout {
  display: block;
}

/*
.checkout {
  display: block;
  float: none;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0.625rem 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #666;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0 none;
  outline: 0 none;
}
*/

.checkout {
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 0.625rem 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #00a7d1;
  transition: background-color 0.5s linear 0s;
}

.checkout:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #00c5f7;
}

.strike {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

.strike>span {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.strike>span:after, .strike>span:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 9999px;
    height: 1px;
    background: #d0d0d0;
}

.strike>span:before {
    right: 100%;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.strike>span:after, .strike>span:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 9999px;
    height: 1px;
    background: #d0d0d0;
}

.strike>span:after {
    left: 100%;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.basket-heading span {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.checkout-subscribe {
    padding: 20px 0px 10px 0px;
}

.checkout-subscribe a {
    background-color: #618b9e66;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    color: #2c383c;
    font-size: 14px;
}


.slect-pay, .data-payment {
  width: 69%;
  padding: 162px 0px 20px 15px;
}

.slect-pay h2, .info-pay h2 {
  padding-bottom: 18px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}



.group-radio, .themes-payment {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.group-radio label {
  padding: 0px 50px 0px 2px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .basket-cart,
  .basket,
  .summary,
  .basket-item,
  .basket-remove-item {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .basket-labels {
    display: none;
  }
  .basket-module {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
  }
  .basket-item {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
  }
  .product-image {
    width: 40%;
  }
  .product-details {
    width: 60%;
  }
  .basket-price,
  .basket-subtotal {
    width: 33%;
  }
  .basket-quantity {
    text-align: center;
    width: 34%;
  }
  .quantity-field {
    float: none;
  }
  .basket-remove-item {
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 0.75rem;
    position: relative;
  }
  .basket-remove-item button {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .summary {
    margin-top: 1.25rem;
    position: relative;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 641px) and (max-width: 960px) {
  .basket-cart {
    padding: 0 1rem 0 0;
  }
  .summary {
    width: 28%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  #basket {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .product-details {
    padding: 0 1rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="basket">
  <div class="basket-labels">
    <ul>
      <li class="item-heading">Item</li>
      <li class="item-price">Price</li>
      <li class="item-quantity">Quantity</li>
      <li class="item-subtotal">Subtotal</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
            <div class="basket-product">
    <div class="basket-item">
      <div class="product-image">
        <img class="product-frame" src="https://download.qnap.com/QPKG/img/python_640x400.png" alt="Curso básico &amp; avanzado de programación algoritmo...">        </div>
      <div class="product-details">
        <h2>Product Python Download 4, new doc...</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="basket-price">
        $100.00       </div>
      <div class="basket-quantity">
        1       </div>
      <div class="basket-subtotal">
        100.00       </div>
      <div class="basket-remove-item">
        <a href="removecart.php?itemId=9">Remove</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Entonces no se si la mejor alternativa es usar estilos mediante uso de `flex / flexbox`, no se si en un orden fijo pueda ser mejor, para evitar ese mal diseño.

Pueden explicarme, como hacer que el diseño sea agradable, por favor, que los cambios que se me sean explicado solo sean en los estilos `CSS`, basados a mi código y no estructuras nuevas de código `HTML`.

Comment: Estas en tu derecho de no querer cambiar tu código html, pero ¿podrías explicar el porqué? La solución más sencilla sería hacer una tabla. Sino por mucho que metas flexbox o grids va a ser un pequeño infierno cuadrar una lista de 4 elementos con un div con 6 divs en su interior, y el resultado no va a ser muy responsive.

Comment: Definitivamente este es un component hecho con muchisima facilidad ayudandote de una tabla; a pesar de ser posible con Flexbox o CSS Grid la cantidad de codigo necesaria junto al potencial para que un cambio pequeño arruine todo el diseño es muchisimo. Hay alguna razon en particular para no usar una `table`?

Answer (score 2):

Reutilicé los estilos que usaste para basket-item y añadí un par de columnas extra para que coincida con las columnas usadas en cada basket item:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, ::after, ::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    color: #222222;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background-color: #f8f9fb;
}

ul li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    list-style: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

img,
.basket-module,
.basket-labels,
.basket-product {
  width: 100%;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

#basket {
  clear: both;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 1rem 0;
}

.item-heading,
.item-price,
.item-quantity,
.item-subtotal,
.basket,
.basket-module,
.basket-labels,
.basket-item,
.basket-price,
.basket-quantity,
.basket-subtotal,
.basket-product,
.product-image,
.product-image-order,
.product-details-order,
.product-details {
  float: left;
}

.item-heading,
.item-price,
.item-quantity,
.item-subtotal {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item-heading {
    padding-left: 10.375rem;
}
.item-price {
    padding-left: 13.7rem;
}

.item-quantity {
      padding-left: 7.5rem;
}
.item-subtotal {
  padding-left: 7.1rem;
}

.basket {
  width: 70%;
}

.basket,
.basket-cart {
  padding: 0 1rem;
  /*padding-top: 150px;*/
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.basket-cart {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
}

.basket-module {
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.basket-labels {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-top: 1.625rem;
}

.basket-item {
  width: 100%; /*55*/
}


.basket-price {
  width: 19%;
}

.basket-quantity {
  width: 15%;
}

.basket-subtotal {
  width: 5%;
}

.basket-subtotal {
  text-align: right;
}

.basket-remove-item {
  /*bottom: 1.125rem;*/
  float: right;
  /*position: absolute;*/
  right: 0;
  text-align: right;
  /*width: 45%;*/
}

.basket-remove-item button {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #777;
  float: none;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}


.basket-product {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  position: relative;
}

.product-image {
  width: 10%; /*25% 35%*/
}

.product-image-order {
  width: 14%;
}

.product-frame {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

.product-details {
  width: 35%;/*70% 65%*/
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.product-details h2 {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.product-details-order {
  width: 81%;
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.product-details-order h2 {
    font-size: 13px;
}

.summary {
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  padding: 1rem;
  /*position: fixed;*/
  width: 250px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.summary-total-items {
  color: #666;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.summary-subtotal {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.subtotal-title,
.subtotal-value,
.promo-title,
.promo-value,
.discount-title,
.discount-value,
.expand-title,
.expand-coupon,
.total-title,
.total-value {
  color: #111;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.subtotal-value,
.total-value {
  text-align: right;
}

.total-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.promo-title,.discount-title {
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
}

.promo-value,.discount-value {
  color: #8B0000;
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
  width: 30%;
}

.expand-form {
  display:none;
  clear: both;
}

.expand-coupon {
  color: #4D8FE5;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: right;
}

.promo-code-field {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
  width: 48%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
  -o-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
}

.promo-code-field:hover,
.promo-code-field:focus {
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

.responseCoupon {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0.9;
  position: absolute; 
  bottom: 71px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  left: 15px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 250px;
}

.promo-code {
  font-size: 16px;
    /*text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-left: 20px;*/
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
}

.delete-promo-code {
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 13px;
  /*
  color: #8B0000;
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    width: 30%;*/
}

.summary-total {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.summary-subtotal,
.summary-total {
  clear: both;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
}

.summary-promo {
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.summary-checkout {
  display: block;
}

/*
.checkout {
  display: block;
  float: none;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0.625rem 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #666;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0 none;
  outline: 0 none;
}
*/

.checkout {
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 0.625rem 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #00a7d1;
  transition: background-color 0.5s linear 0s;
}

.checkout:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #00c5f7;
}

.strike {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

.strike>span {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.strike>span:after, .strike>span:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 9999px;
    height: 1px;
    background: #d0d0d0;
}

.strike>span:before {
    right: 100%;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.strike>span:after, .strike>span:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 9999px;
    height: 1px;
    background: #d0d0d0;
}

.strike>span:after {
    left: 100%;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.basket-heading span {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.checkout-subscribe {
    padding: 20px 0px 10px 0px;
}

.checkout-subscribe a {
    background-color: #618b9e66;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    color: #2c383c;
    font-size: 14px;
}


.slect-pay, .data-payment {
  width: 69%;
  padding: 162px 0px 20px 15px;
}

.slect-pay h2, .info-pay h2 {
  padding-bottom: 18px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}



.group-radio, .themes-payment {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.group-radio label {
  padding: 0px 50px 0px 2px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .basket-cart,
  .basket,
  .summary,
  .basket-item,
  .basket-remove-item {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .basket-labels {
    display: none;
  }
  .basket-module {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
  }
  .basket-item {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
  }
  .product-image {
    width: 40%;
  }
  .product-details {
    width: 60%;
  }
  .basket-price,
  .basket-subtotal {
    width: 33%;
  }
  .basket-quantity {
    text-align: center;
    width: 34%;
  }
  .quantity-field {
    float: none;
  }
  .basket-remove-item {
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 0.75rem;
    position: relative;
  }
  .basket-remove-item button {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .summary {
    margin-top: 1.25rem;
    position: relative;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 641px) and (max-width: 960px) {
  .basket-cart {
    padding: 0 1rem 0 0;
  }
  .summary {
    width: 28%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  #basket {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .product-details {
    padding: 0 1rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="basket">
  <div class="basket-labels">
    <ul>
      <li class="product-image">Item</li>
      <li class="product-details">Item</li>
      <li class="basket-price">Price</li>
      <li class="basket-quantity">Quantity</li>
      <li class="basket-subtotal">Subtotal</li>
      <li class="basket-remove-item">Actions</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="basket-product">
    <div class="basket-item">
      <div class="product-image">
        <img class="product-frame" src="https://download.qnap.com/QPKG/img/python_640x400.png" alt="Curso básico &amp; avanzado de programación algoritmo...">
      </div>
      <div class="product-details">
        <h2>Product Python Download 4, new doc...</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="basket-price">$100.00</div>
      <div class="basket-quantity">1</div>
      <div class="basket-subtotal">100.00</div>
      <div class="basket-remove-item">
        <a href="removecart.php?itemId=9">Remove</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Es curioso como se parece esta pregunta a [ésta que respondí esta tarde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55184543/having-trouble-achieving-specific-css-grid-layout/55186526#55186526) ¿Hay un concurso de hacer Carritos de la compra y te dan el HTML y debes usar flexbox para resolverlo?

Bueno, te respondo tu pregunta que es algo diferente de la del enlace:

1. Como dice @Mikel Ferreiro, para contenido tabulado, que es tu caso lo mejor es un tabla. Puedes añadirle la propiedad `table-layout: fixed;` para tener más control sobre los elementos que no quieres que crezcan.
2. Para que el código sea más semántico, ya que no usas tabla, al menos deberías usar una de dos: o listas `<ul>` o mejor incluso `<article>`.
3. Si prefieres, por la razón que sea, no cambiar tu HTML, @Francisto Tena ya te lo ha solucionado. Aunque no usando flexbox, por lo que las medidas están fijadas a un porcentaje en vez repartir el espacio disponible según la necesidad del contenido.
4. Para lograr esa adaptación están las tablas o en todo caso, flexbox combinado con medidas fijas para los elementos de la derecha.

Ya que no te has molestado en limpiar el css para facilitarnos la tarea, yo te doy la solución, pero tú la tendrás que adaptar a tu código.

[Shopping cart con flexbox](https://codepen.io/jesuke/pen/aMYGdv)

Comment: Gracias por la recompensa

Answer (score 0):

Probá agregando esto:

```
.basket-labels ul, .basket-product .basket-item{
    display: flex;
}
li[class^="item"], .basket-item > div[class^="basket"], .basket-item > div[class^="product"]{
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center;
}
li[class^='item']:first-child{
    flex: 2;
}
```

Esto al final de los 'basket-labels':

```
<li class='item-actions'></li>
```

Y borrando esta parte del css:

```
.item-heading {
    padding-left: 10.375rem;
}
.item-price {
    padding-left: 13.7rem;
}

.item-quantity {
      padding-left: 7.5rem;
}
.item-subtotal {
  padding-left: 7.1rem;
}
```